# Deploying ASP.NET Project with Mysql DB to azure web app via visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I am new here, and new for tech as well.

I am deploying an ASP.NET project with Mysql DB to azure web app, I tried many times, when I publish the code from visual studio, it failed and here is the error:

rror details: Connected to the remote computer ("webappsuly2.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site. Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Dentistry 0.

I tried every single thing but still couldn't fix it, I would appreciate your help.

I am expecting a step by step guideline, creating the web app, the mysql db, and then configuring the connection between the DB and the web app and then publishing the code via visual studio.

I would appreciate if you help,
Best Regards,

Comment: @Brzan Hassan Are you using Asp.net core MVC or .net 4.8

Answer (score 0):

I tried a sample ASP. NET MVC Core 6 with MySQL server and successfully deployed my web app to Azure App Service.

Ensure that the logged Azure account credentials in Visual Studio are valid and that your Azure subscription is active with the required access rights.

I added the following lines to my program.cs class.

**Program.cs** :

```cs
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<empContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySQL(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlConnection")));
```

**appsettings.json**:

```json
 "ConnectionStrings": {
   "MySqlConnection": "server=localhost;port=3306;user=userName;password=password;database=databasename"
 }
```

**.csproj** :

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="6.0.23" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.23" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.23">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="DataObjects\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Local Output** :

[image]

I created an Azure Database for MySQL.

[image]

Connected to the MySQL Workbench as shown below:

[image]

Download an SSL certificate from Networking in the Azure Database for MySQL server.

[image]

provide the correct path for the SSL Certificate.

[image]

Revise the connection string in appsettings.json as follows:

```json
 "ConnectionStrings": {
   "MySqlConnection": "server=kaserver123.mysql.database.azure.com;port=3306;user=userName;password=password;database=databasename"
 }
```

I successfully deployed the web app to Azure App Service, as shown below:

[image]

**Azure App service Output** :

[image]